# How do I get the ID of a model in a collection after it was created as part of a nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `User` model, which `:has_many :widgets`

Here is the 'edit' method:

```
  def edit
    @user = current_user
    @user.widgets.build   
  end
```

I have an edit view which contains a user form and a widget form nested within it

In my `UserController#update` method, I save the data...all working as designed.

After save, I want to send the user to Widget#show with the ID of the widget that was just added to User.widgets

How do I get that ID?

Here is my update method:

```
 def update
    @user = User.find(params[:user][:id], :include => [:widgets])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
       redirect_to widget_path(????), notice: 'Your new Widget is ready' }
    end
  end
```

Comment: One technique that will work in certain circumstances is to call @user.widgets.last.id after you update_attributes. However, that won't work if people other than you can add widgets to the user collection at the same time. So I'm still looking for a way to do this with concurrent updates going on.

Comment: When updating a user, you always create new widgets? If so, can't you create the widget like this, instead of relying on `update_attributes`: `widget = @user.widgets.create(params[:widget])`? That way you can use the `widget` variable for the redirect.

Comment: The problem with that is that I'm updating User info at the same time. So when I call User.update_attributes, it'll create the widget for me whether I've created it myself or not. It's possible that I could create the widget and then delete it from params[] before calling update_attributes. That seems like excessive hoop-jumping, but that might be what's required in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you scope the `@user.widgets.last.id` request so that you are assured of getting their last widget, something like: `@user.widgets.created_by(@user).last.id`